# How to stop sliding anythingSlider(jQuery plugin)?

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

I need to stop sliding on `anythingslider` if user wants to go back when current page = 1. So I don't want rotate. I tried

```
onSlideBegin : function(e, slider){
    return false;
} // there is no check I just need to know how to stop sliding
```

but still sliding.
Thanks

Comment: Try: `$('.anythingSlider').data('AnythingSlider').startStop(false);`.

Comment: i tried this don't work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe???

```
// Slideshow options 
  autoPlay            : false,     // If true, the slideshow will start running; replaces "startStopped" option 
  autoPlayLocked      : false,     // If true, user changing slides will not stop the slideshow 
  autoPlayDelayed     : false,     // If true, starting a slideshow will delay advancing slides; if false, the slider will immediately advance to the next slide when slideshow starts 
  pauseOnHover        : true,      // If true & the slideshow is active, the slideshow will pause on hover 
  stopAtEnd           : false,     // If true & the slideshow is active, the slideshow will stop on the last page. This also stops the rewind effect when infiniteSlides is false. 
  playRtl             : false,     // If true, the slideshow will move right-to-left
```